# Expand static TableViewCell with UI Switch

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I have been searching for this answer and my problem seems to be two-fold: (1) answers are from 2011 and I'm too new to Swift to translate old code and (2) in implementing the code I have found, it changes the height of ALL the cells in the tableView.  I have some cells that are larger than others and I need them to be left alone by this.

My question is how to target a single cell's height to expand and contract based on a switch being toggled and have it not effect the height of any other cells.

iOS "create new calendar" event is what I'm looking for and the expandable cell will have a date picker in it, if that matters.  Also, I'm using STATIC cells...some being custom and some using built-in features.

EDIT -- added code

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2 {
        pickerVisible = !pickerVisible
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2 && toggle.isOn == false {
        return 0.0
    }
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 3 {
        if toggle.isOn == false || pickerVisible == false {
            return 0.0
        }
        return 165.0
    }
    return 44.0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 44.0
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: @shallowThought - edited above to add code.  Thanks.

Comment: In general it would be great if you link the old answer as well.

Comment: @Honey I get that, but the old answer is where I made some of my progress, but doesn't address the effect on other cells.  Basically, the old answer is my code above.